# How do I get the curernt username of someone logged-in using JDBCRealm in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbcrealm

I'm running Tomcat 6 and have implemented JDBCRealm to authenticate my users.  I've got everything setup and authentication is working just fine.

My question is: how do I programmatically get the username of the user who is logged-in?  Is this a session attribute that gets set?  A Cookie?

This seems very trivial but I'm stumped.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try getting this information from [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) using `getUserPrincipal()` call.

Comment: That seems to have done it!  Thanks!  This returns a Principal object containing the username along with it's roles, which is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!!